# Specify table-column on "in" operator

Tags: mysql, sql, database, shortcut

i would like to know if there is any shortcut to specify the column where `IN` have to check for matches.

Example:
Instead of this:

```
select * 
from table1
where id in(
    select column
    from table2
)
```

something like this:

```
select * 
from table1
where id in table2.column
```

I know the existence of `TABLE` for `IN, ANY, SOME` to specify a table, but it works only if the table specified is composed by just 1 column

**EDIT**: using `join` is not an option, because the real use i was looking for is on a `NOT IN` operator, and also `JOIN` create duplicates sometimes like in a one to many relation

Comment: There is no shortcut.

Comment: Note that MySQL often optimizes `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` poorly. It does better with `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut like that in SQL.  Let me explain why.

In a query, *all* table references need to be made in the `FROM` clause.  Hence, you cannot simply refer to `table2.col` *unless* `table2` has been defined in the `FROM` clause.  `table2` is actually an *alias*, which defaults to the table name.

From a performance perspective, I would recommend `exists`:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where exists (select column
              from table2 t2
              where t2.column = t1.id
             )
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `table2(column)` and has the same semantics as `in`.

Comment: sorry, how the match algorithm works on exists? it check on the primary key or the entire row has to be the same?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia . . . `exists` checks if the subquery returns any rows.  This is quite clearly explained in the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html.

Answer (score 1):

Using a JOIN is a bit shorter. At least it does not require a subquery or another `SELECT ... FROM`.

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.column
```

Although this simple example is an inner join, not a semi-join. An inner join is different because it produces one row per matched row in table2. A semi-join only produces one row for each row in table1, even if it matches multiple rows in table2.

If you want to simulate a semi-join, use `DISTINCT` to reduce the result to one row per row of table1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.* 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.column
```

If you want to check for something like NOT EXISTS, use an exclusion join:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.column
WHERE table2.column IS NULL
```

No need to use DISTINCT on the outer join example. There will be no row duplication from the join, because it can only "match no rows" once.

Comment: thanks for the answer, what if instead i would check for not existence in the second table?

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . A `JOIN` is not equivalent, because `IN` does not produce duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, as I wrote above, it does not do a semi-join. You could simulate it using `SELECT DISTINCT ...` I will edit the above to make that more clear.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . And that would might negate any performance gain from using a `JOIN`.

Comment: I thought the question was about using shorter query syntax. Performance was not mentioned. :-)